# How to derive Action type from mapping object for useReducer dispatch type safety?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-generics, use-reducer

## Preamble

Typically, I'll define a `reducer` like below so that I have type safety with the `dispatch` method:

```ts
const setWhatever = (state: State, payload: Partial<State>) => ({ ...state, ...payload });

// Maps an action type to an action handler
const actions = {
  SET_WHATEVER: setWhatever,
}

type Action =
  | { type: 'SET_WHATEVER', payload: Parameters<typeof setWhatever>[1] }

const reducer = (state: State, action: Action) => actions[action.type](state, action.payload);

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {});
```

The repetitive nature of the `type Action` is slightly annoying. Is there any way for me to derive the `type Action` based off of the `const actions`?

## Current v1 Solution

I actually have a mostly-working example of a `CreateActions<T>` Mapped Type. Here's the [CodeSandbox (v1)](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/derive-type-action-vdlg4q?file=%2Fsrc%2FuseLogic.tsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A45%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A45%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A37%7D%5D) example.

```ts
type CreateActions<T extends typeof actions> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    type: K;
    payload: T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? Parameters<T[K]>[1] : never;
  };
}[keyof T];

type Action = CreateActions<typeof actions>;
```

But there are a couple more things that don't make this perfect.

1. The `reducer` needs an extra `as never` casting to make some linting error messages go away:

````ts
/**
 * The `as never` below "fixes" the following typing error message:
 * ```
 * Argument of type 'string | number | Partial<{ name: string; age: number; }> | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
 *  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)
 * ```
 * 
 * QUESTION: is there a better way to fix the error message?
 */
const reducer = (state: State, action: Action): State =>
  actions[action.type](state, action.payload as never);
````

2. I'm forced to have a `payload` in the dispatch. Anyway I can make some actions not require a payload?

```ts
dispatch({ type: 'RESET', payload: undefined }); // linter complains with dispatch({ type: 'RESET' });
```

## Current v2 Solution

Updated [CodeSandbox (v2)](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/derive-type-action-v2-43pmho?file=%2Fsrc%2FuseLogic.tsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A4%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A60%2C%22startColumn%22%3A3%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A57%7D%5D) example with the final solution thanks to @ryskajakub.

```ts
type Payload<T> = T extends (...args: any[]) => any
  ? Parameters<T>[1]
  : never;

type CreateActions<T extends typeof actions> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Payload<T[K]> extends undefined
    ? {
        type: K;
        // defined so reducer doesn't complain about missing action.payload
        payload?: undefined;
      }
    : {
        type: K;
        payload: Payload<T[K]>;
      };
}[keyof T];

/** Hover over Action to see the discriminated union type. */
type Action = CreateActions<typeof actions>;

const reducer: ActionHandler<Action> = (state, action): State =>
  (actions[action.type] as ActionHandler<typeof action["payload"]>)(
    state,
    action.payload
  );
```

So now I can call `dispatch({ type: 'RESET' })` without any typing error.

There is a "gotcha" in that I can also call `dispatch({ type: 'RESET', payload: undefined })` without any typing error, but I don't care about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the first question, you can also make a conditional type based on the type of the payload. If payload is such that you want to ignore it, you can create a type where the payload won't be a part of object.

```
type Payload<T> =  T extends (...args: any[]) => any ? Parameters<T>[1] : never

type CreateActions<T extends typeof actions> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Payload<T[K]> extends undefined ? {
    type: K
  } : {
    type: K;
    payload: Payload<T[K]>;
  };
}[keyof T];
```

It would be best if you would put the second question in separate question.

Comment: Thank you. I had to make the type `{ type: K; payload?: never; }` so I can pass in `action.payload` in the reducer, but it still gave me the desired result of being able to call `dispatch({ type: 'RESET' })` in the end.

Then I was able to get rid of the `as never` with some casting. `(actions[action.type] as ActionHandler<typeof action["payload"]>)(state, action.payload)`. I created a new CodeSandbox with the final result.